# on submit redux form looping axios post for multible values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, react-redux

enter code herei have form list of checkboxes i want on redux form submit to post each value to axios api, in the following code im showing the submit function,

values={example1:true,example2:true,example3:false,example4:true}
the expected output in my code to print each key then post it
but innow its doing like this
will do loop and console(example1,....,example4) after this will call the post 4 times for the one same key

```
submit(values) {
let data={
    "status":"INVITED",
    "buyerId": localStorage.getItem("companyId"),
    "joinType": "B",
    "supplierId": ""          
}
for (var key in values) {
    if (values[key]) {

        data.supplierId=key
       console.log(key)
       postWithAuth("networkmgtservice/api/networks",data).then((response) => {
        let status=response.data.statusCode;
        if(status="000"){
              console.log(key)
            $(`#${keyVar}`).html("Successfully sent")
        }
        else if(status=="999"){

            $(`#${keyVar}`).html(response.data.errorDescription)
        }
      })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a codepen to show what the problem is? 

I think you need to call for loop with `var key in values.keys(){ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `var` to declare your loop variables when inside loop you are doing async task as variables declared by `var` don't maintain their state and gets updated to last value in your loop as loop is always faster than your API call, so your loop variables will only persist value of last item in your map. Instead use `let` to declare loop variable as they maintain state.

```
submit(values) {
let data={
    "status":"INVITED",
    "buyerId": localStorage.getItem("companyId"),
    "joinType": "B",
    "supplierId": ""          
}
for (let key in values) {
    if (values[key]) {
       let requestData = {...data};
       requestData.supplierId=key
       console.log(key)
       postWithAuth("networkmgtservice/api/networks",requestData)
           .then((response) => {
                let status=response.data.statusCode;
                if(status="000"){
                    console.log(key)
                    $(`#${keyVar}`).html("Successfully sent")
                }
                else if(status=="999"){
                    $(`#${keyVar}`).html(response.data.errorDescription)
                }
           })
            .catch((error) => {
                 console.log(error)
             })
     }
}
```

Comment: Woah, I didn't know this. Thanks Arpit!

Comment: @ShivamGupta if it helped you, can you please upvote the answer as a token of appreciation :)

Comment: Sure. Just did :)

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal thanks alot for ur reply, actually  i tried it still the loop correct but the api call calling last value of the loop 4 times :( , what do u think?

Comment: thank all, actually i have fixed the problem is with foreach, i replace it with object.keys(values).map((key)=>{}) it's worked fine
instead of for (let key in values)

Comment: It might be because, we were using the same data object(not creating new for each iteration) and changing the value of 1 key. Can you try this one? Also can you post the working solution?